# Alterar posicionamento da barra de rolagem em uma div

Tags: javascript, css, div, rolamento, navegação

Por padrão, em um menu horizontal o conteúdo é lido da esquerda para a direita, como nesta imagem: [image: barra de rolagem à esquerda]

Entretanto, gostaria que quando o conteúdo fosse carregado, a barra de rolagem fosse, digamos, movida automaticamente para a direita, como nesta imagem: [image: barra de rolagem à direita]

Isto é possível?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você estiver usando jQuery, poderá usar o método [`scrollLeft()`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/). Um exemplo:

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function () {
  var $target = $('.content');
  $target.scrollLeft($target.outerWidth() + 20);
});
```

```css
.content {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 1rem;
  max-width: 500px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.btn {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sit amet turpis lacus. Curabitur efficitur est mi, in fermentum arcu lobortis ut.
</div>

<button class="btn">Clique-me</button>
```

No seu caso, bastaria mudar o evento de 'clique' para quando a página carregar:

```
$(function () {
  var $target = $('seletor-do-elemento');
  $target.scrollLeft($target.outerWidth() + 20);
});
```

#### Referência:

- [`.scrollLeft()`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/);
- [`.outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/).

Comment: Luiz Felipe, funcionou também! Consegui utilizando o `direction:rtl` em CSS puro. Obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Vc pode usar `flex-direction: row-reverse;` para indicar que a ordem dos elementos vai começar de *traz para frente*, dessa forma o `scroll` vai para o final do `container`. Ai basta vc reordenar as div para ficar no seu agrado.

Veja como fica no exemplo:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.item {
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f00;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: consegui utilizando o `direction:rtl` Obrigado!

Comment: @Vítor legal é uma opção tb. Só lembre-se que RTL significa "right to left" é uma orientação para leitores de tela para texto que devem ser lidos da direita para a esquerda como o Japones etc... então RTL não seria bom pelo lado semântico da coisa. Principalmente tendo outras alternativas tanto com CSS quanto com JS. Mas não deixa de ser uma solução :D

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma mais direta de fazer isso com javascript é:

```
var element = document.getElementById('ID-DO-ELEMENTO');
element.scrollTo(element.scrollWidth, 0);
```